# Superset not retuning data for chart via api

Tags: apache-superset

I am facing an issue with apache superset 1.5.3 not returning data for an chart.

- The chart is shown in the superset UI without issues.
- I am able to retrieve its details via the `api/v1/chart/{pk}` endpoint
- Calling `api/v1/chart/{pk}/data` on this chart returns an error:

{
"message": "Error: Empty query?"
}

- Same endpoint works fine with other charts

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong and how I can retrieve data for this specific chart? This chart uses an virtual dataset (custom query against BigQuery)

Comment: I think it is related to the fact that this is an "legacy" chart, which is not echarts. Can anyone suggest how to fetch data for legacy charts in superset?